# Why temp tables are being created automatically in database

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-code-first, sql-server-2014, ef-core-2.1

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1 with .NET Core 2.0. I am using code first approach. I am seeing sometime temp tables are getting created in the database.

Here is the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Odds is a table created by me using EFCore but when app is running continuously for sometime then these Temp Tables are getting created and I can also see some data in these tables as well.

Can anyone please help me in this. How I can fix this issue?